# C - printf in Visual Studio Interface

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, printf

Is there anyway to print into a textarea or something using printf( or something similar)?
I need to print chars with different colours including spaces.
A table can be a solution if is possible to "paint" the cells.
Using labels would be awesome but is in a random IxJ (columnsxrows) and is impossible to select each one.

thanks

Comment: Are you trying to write to the visual studio output window, to a windows form, or to the console?

Comment: `sprintf()` will be your new best friend.

Comment: I have it using terminal (command line) and using printf to show.
But I've to use "graphical interface" so GTK I don't know and and windows form should be a easy way. Change from unix to windows isn't a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mention `printf`, I assume you want to output to the console. You can use [SetConsoleTextAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686047%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to set the foreground and background colour to be used.